# Python and Gtk - which GTK version is being used?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

#print Gtk.GTK_MAJOR_VERSION

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

That is my code, how can I know which version of Gtk is being used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following functions to get the version information:

```
Gtk.get_major_version()
Gtk.get_minor_version()
Gtk.get_micro_version()
```

Comment: Links to the docs for those wondering: https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/gtk-constants.html; https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Feature-Test-Macros.html

Answer (score 0):

For check in .gir files:

```
grep -rin 'get_[a-zA-Z]*_version' /usr/share/gir-1.0/Gtk-3.0.gir
```

Example output:

```
grep -rin 'get_[a-zA-Z]*_version' /usr/share/gir-1.0/Gtk-3.0.gir
108409:    <function name="get_major_version"
108410:              c:identifier="gtk_get_major_version"
108424:    <function name="get_micro_version"
108425:              c:identifier="gtk_get_micro_version"
108439:    <function name="get_minor_version"
108440:              c:identifier="gtk_get_minor_version"
```